# How to convert Json with attributes with dashes to object with fields with underscores?

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I have a string with json with attributes contained dashes. I want to convert it to object with field with underscore. I tried to use Json4s library but got an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json4s.package$MappingException: No usable value for some_field
Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String
```

Could you help me write some custom policy for fields with dashes.

Converting code:

```
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods.parse

object Converter extends App {

  case class Key(some_field: String, some_other_field: String)
  
  def jsonToObject[A](data: String)(implicit manifest: Manifest[A]): A = {
    import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    parse(data).extract[A]
  }

  val input = "{\"some-field\":\"first\",\"some-other-field\":\"second\"}"

  val someObject = jsonToObject[Key](input)

  println(s"${someObject.some_field}  ${someObject.some_other_field}")
}
```

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E29C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)! So do not use it for parsing of an untrusted input.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not limited to use json4s then you can do it easily with [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala):

1. Add dependencies:

```scala
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter-scala" %% "jsoniter-scala-core"   % "2.6.2",
  "com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter-scala" %% "jsoniter-scala-macros" % "2.6.2" % "compile-internal" // or "provided", but it is required only in compile-time
)
```

2. Derive a codec and use it for parsing:

```scala
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.macros._
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.core._

object Converter extends App {
  case class Key(some_field: String, some_other_field: String)

  implicit val codec: JsonValueCodec[Key] =
    JsonCodecMaker.make(CodecMakerConfig.withFieldNameMapper(JsonCodecMaker.`enforce-kebab-case`))

  val input = "{\"some-field\":\"first\",\"some-other-field\":\"second\"}"
  val someObject = readFromString(input)
  println(s"${someObject.some_field}  ${someObject.some_other_field}")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for respond, I limited in dependencies. Only json4s now.